# Сбилось разрешение экрана ноутбука после замены матрицы

Tags: экран, разрешение, slackware

У меня проблема следующего свойства. Неделю назад навернулся ноут (ASUS M515D), полетела матрица. Нашёл магазин, купил, там же заменили. Всё бы ничего, но сбилось разрешение экрана. Было 1366x768, а теперь стоит 1920x1080. Вывод xrendr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 
194mm
   1920x1080     59.98*+
   1680x1050     59.98 
   1280x1024     59.98 
   1440x900      59.98 
   1280x800      59.98 
   1280x720      59.98 
   1024x768      59.98 
   800x600       59.98 
   640x480       59.98 
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Система Slackware64 current. Вопрос, безусловно, в первую очередь к слакварщикам.

Но я думаю, что дело здесь не в иксах, до старта X-сервера, такая же беда. Как можно это дело исправить?